# Start Directory in Windows Explorer running Vista not set properly?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, explorer

When I right click on Windows Explorer, select Properties, it opens a panel, I set the value of "Start In" to "C:\", which means I want it to point to my C: drive when I open explorer, but it's not working, it always points to "Documents". On XP I did the same thing and it worked, but now I got this new PC with Vista, it doesn't work? How to fix this?

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking programming questions. You may be able to get help with this at one of the sites listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 2):

Use the explorer start params, e.g.,:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,D:\Downloads
```

Comment: Yep, that's it ! I'm surprised the "Start in" is good for nothing.

Comment: the "start in" only sets the 'current working directory' for the process. It doesn't mean that the process (in this case explorer) has to *show* that directory.